# How many ways can you select $5$ marbles if you select at least one from each color?

Tags: permutations, combinations

You have $5$ identical black marbles, $5$ identical green marbles and $3$ identical red marbles. How many ways can you choose $5$ marbles with at least one from each color?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own work on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Note that you wish to solve the equation $b + g + r = 5$ in the positive integers subject to the restriction that $r \leq 3$.

Answer (score 2):

First we pick out $1$ of each colored ball. Next, we need to pick out the remaining $2$ balls.

The number of ways to do so is exactly the number of solutions to

$$A + B + C = 2$$

where $A, B, C$ are non-negative integers such that $A, B \le 4$, $C \le 2$.

Since the upper bounds of $A, B, C$ exceed or are equal to their necessary sum, we can safely ignore those bounds and use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and the  [Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) to deduce that there are

$$\binom{2 + 2}{2} = 6$$

ways of picking out the remaining $2$ balls.

Comment: Nice idea to model it with the equation. Given the nature of the question, could you add the definition/link of the binomial coefficient just for completeness?

Comment: Good idea, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have one of each colour in our grab, we already have taken 3 of our five marbles. Leaves 2 spots to be filled by 4 blacks, 4 greens and 2 reds. If our two extra marbles are the same colour, we have 3 clear options (2 blacks, 2 greens, or 2 reds). If our two remaining marbles are different colors, there are also 3 possibilities: 1 black 1 green, 1 black 1 red, and 1 green 1 red. We hence have 3+3=6 possibilities to grab marbles in which we have at least one of each color. I hope this helps!